# Create UIPageControl to hold icons

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

I want to create an application with landing view that shows a list of icons, each will push a new view to the navController, something like Facebook iPhone app! Is there something that i can use, or should I build it myself? And where can i find samples that shows how to do that? When user hold her finger on one icon, all icons start to dance/move indicating edit mode which allow the user to rearrange icons, is this also something i need to build?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create an UINavigationConytoller based application.Whwn a user holds a finger on icon,just push the view to desired NavigationController. You can create the icons as UIButton.

Sample Code:

//h file

```
@interface RecipesMenuViewController : UIViewController {

}
- (IBAction)getStateWiseList:(id)sender;
@end
```

//m file

```
#import "RecipesMenuViewController.h"
#import "MenuLevel1ViewController.h"

@implementation RecipesMenuViewController

- (IBAction)getStateWiseList:(id)sender     {
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[MenuLevel1ViewController alloc] initWithID:1] animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So i should build the views, place the buttons in the right position, and use the UIPageControl if my icons/options do not fit in one page. I was hopping that there is a template or component that I can use, which can distribute buttons / icons on the scree and take care of the paging for me, I suppose that this component dose not exist?